# How many digits will $5^{4^{3^2}}$ produce?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

According to Wolfram Alpha, $5^{4^{3^2}}$ evaluates to an integer with $183\,231$ digits. How does one find out how many digits such a calculation will produce?

Comment: This number is $5^{262144}$. So it has exactly $262144 \log_{10}5 = 183230.\dots$ digits.

Comment: The number of digits of $x$ in decimal is around $\log_{10} x$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A number $n \in \mathbf N^+$ has $\lfloor\log_{10}n\rfloor+1$ digits. For $n = 5^{4^{3^2}}$, we have 
\begin{align*}
  \log_{10} 5^{4^{3^2}} &= 4^9 \cdot \log_{10} 5\\
           &= 262\,144 \cdot \log_{10} 5\\
           &\approx 183\,230.8
\end{align*}
So $n$ has $183\,231$ digits.

Comment: dont we have any other method...is it possible always to find like this for a competive exams???@martini

Comment: @gloom Are you sure that $5^2=10$?

Comment: oh..I am sorry...i did a blunder..@Asydot

Comment: I do not know any other method, to be honest. But often an approximation can be done by hand (and hence in an exam): $4^9$ is $2^{18}$, hence $256 \cdot 1024$ (now multiply by hand), and $5^{10} = 3\,125^2 = 9\,765\,625$, which is slightly less than $10^{7}$, so $\log_{10} 5^{10}$ is slightly less than $7$, that is $\log_{10} 5$ is slightly less than $0.7$, so the number is something less $262\,144 \cdot 0.7 = 183500.8$